# Smooth function, lateral limit and trigonometry

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Let $\theta: (t_0-\varepsilon, t_0)\to\mathbb{R},\ \theta\in C^{\infty}((t_0-\varepsilon,t_0))$. Knowing that the following two limits exist:

$\lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} \cos^2 \theta(t)$ and $\lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} \sin\theta(t)\cos\theta(t)$, is it true that

$\exists\ \lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} \cos \theta(t)$ and $\exists\ \lim\limits_{t\nearrow t_0} \sin \theta(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since $$\cos 2 \varphi = 2 \cos^2 \varphi - 1 \\ \sin 2 \varphi = 2 \sin \varphi \cos \varphi,$$ the limits $$a = \lim_{t \nearrow t_0} \cos 2 \theta(t) \\ b = \lim_{t \nearrow t_0} \sin 2 \theta(t) $$ exist and $a^2 + b^2 = 1,$ so there is some $\varphi_0$ with $\cos( 2 \varphi_0 ) = a$ and $\sin( 2 \varphi_0 ) = b$. The set $$A = \left\{ \varphi \in \mathbb{R} : | \cos( 2 \varphi ) - a | < \frac{1}{10} \right\}$$ is a disjoint union of open intervals $A_k$, and there is exactly one number of form $\varphi_0 + k \pi$ in each. There is also a $t_1 \in (t_0 - \varepsilon, t_0)$ such that $\cos( 2 \theta(t) ) \in A$ for $t > t_1$ and because $\theta(t)$ is continuous, all values of $\theta(t)$ for $t > t_1$ lie in only one interval $A_k$.

It remains to notice that $\theta(t) \to \varphi_0 + k \pi$ for corresponding $k$, so $\cos \theta(t)$ and $\sin \theta(t)$ converge.